# How do I capture git error message in powershell?

Tags: git, powershell, psake

I am writing a psake script. One of the tasks pulls files from a Github-hosted repository:

```
Framework "4.0"
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

formatTaskName "`n##------ {0} ------##`n"

task DeployToLocalDevelopmentEnvironment {
    # other commands

    exec { git pull origin somebranch } # this is the line that fails

    # other commands
}
```

---

`pull` command fails with the following message:

> From https://github.com/account_name/project_name

It looks like the rest of the error message gets cut off somewhere, so I can't actually get the cause of the problem.

Any thoughts on what how I can view the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea why is happening, but I have found a work-around:

```
$processStartInfo = new-object system.diagnostics.processStartInfo
$processStartInfo.workingDirectory = (get-location).path
$processStartInfo.fileName = "git"
$processStartInfo.arguments = "pull origin $branch_name"
$processStartInfo.useShellExecute = $false

$process = [system.diagnostics.process]::start($processStartInfo);
$process.waitForExit();
```

I have a theory, but can't prove it (yet):

- There are three potential causes: powershell, psake, git
- I was able to rule-out psake by calling git directly from powershell
- All other command-line tools output messages correctly when called from PowerShell, so that rules-out PowerShell
- I suspect the issue is with how git outputs messages to the console
- The next step is to contact PowerShell team to find a proper solution. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: If git thinks it is attached to a console then it outputs to a pager process. If you pipe the output to something else then it won't do that. You are probably getting some of the ANSI codes and breaking on that - as you don't need them you can try 'git --no-pager <cmd>....' or just pipe the output to something as suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Out-File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx) as a log mechanism?

```
exec { git pull origin somebranch | Out-File C:\output.txt }
```

You do not need an "exec" if you perform a "git pull" in *pure* Powershell. Have you tried it without the "exec"? Like so:

```
git pull origin somebranch
```

I believe your problem is with PSAKE truncating your result message. Try it in pure powershell and see what is returned? I do not even know if that's possible...

Comment: Exec is needed in Psake if you want to fail build script when the return code is not 0.

Comment: Can you blend Psake tasks with pure Powershell commands? I do not think exec is required?

Comment: Exec is just syntax sugar. See https://github.com/psake/psake/blob/master/psake.psm1#L130

Comment: @D3vtr0n Exec is just syntactic sugar (as rarouš pointed out).

Comment: @D3vtr0n out-file generates an empty file. Output does not get captured for some reason.

Comment: @D3vtr0n When called natively in powershell, `git pull` just hangs.